# Filtering rows with sentences using panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have address column with 100 rows.
I want to filter out those rows which only have alphabets. I am using panda dataframe to achieve this but not able to succeed.Below is the code i am using

`df3=df1[df1['Addressline'].str.contains('[^a-zA-Z]')]`

data

```
AddressLine(column name)
123 Vasudev Nagar
765 Karol Bagh
Manyata PO 459
KR Puram
Sheshadripuram Post
```

Output

```
KR Puram
Sheshadripuram Post
```

Comment: You could try built-in method isalpha()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
print (df[~df['AddressLine'].str.contains("['0-9']")])
```

O/P:

```
           AddressLine
3             KR Puram
4  Sheshadripuram Post
```

Detail:

```
df['flag']=df['AddressLine'].str.contains("['0-9']")
print (df)
```

O/P:

```
           AddressLine   flag
0    123 Vasudev Nagar   True
1       765 Karol Bagh   True
2       Manyata PO 459   True
3             KR Puram  False
4  Sheshadripuram Post  False
```

Here Flag contains True or False represents is this contains numeric value or not from here you could filter directly.